# QDesktopServices.openUrl() doesn't open network drives

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I have a QLabel that displays a link to a directory the user can click. When the link is to a path mapped to a drive letter, everything works perfectly. When linked to a network drive, nothing happens.

I found a bug related to this problem that seems to indicate it was fixed: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13359

The contents of the label are as follows:

```
<a href="file:///\\nas\data\user\directory">Click Me</a>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is that the *real* contents of the label? What does the actual code look like? The bug report makes it clear there is/was an issue with backslashes, and that can also be a problem in python if you don't escape things properly.

Comment: That is essentially the contents. I obviously changed the real URL and text for the example. I used the context menu to copy the URL and paste it for the example before I changed it to the text above, so all the slashes should be as they are in the real code. I set the text in the QLabel as follows: `label.setText('<a href="file:///{0}">{1}</a>'.format(directory, text))`

Comment: Additionally, if I copy the link location from the context menu and paste it into Firefox, it understands and shows the directory contents as expected

Comment: Did you try the workaround shown in the bug report?

Comment: I tried the workaround, and it still doesn't work. `QDesktopServices.openUrl()` returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was:

```
label = QLabel(...)
label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
#label.setOpenExternalLinks(True) # doesn't work for network paths on Windows
label.linkActivated.connect(os.startfile) # do this instead
```